# Calling JavaScript function in Java

Tags: java, javascript, scriptengine, javascript-engine

I'm trying to send an email using a javascript code in a Java project. Database connection works fine, I already tested it. I got the error: 
**javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: missing ) after formal parameters (#1) in  at line number 1**

Comment: any specific reason for using this method though JavaMail API is available?

Answer (score 2):

The only information of relevance is not readily reported: the *final* JavaScript string executed. Make sure to look at relevant data when debugging. After inspecting the final string it will be apparent *why* it is incorrect and trivial to "fix".

Hint: it will look something like `function sendMail(userblah, foo@bar.qux) { ..`, which is indeed *invalid* JavaScript.

The problem and solution should be self-evident from that - use fixed *parameters* (variable names) in the function declaration and supply *arguments* (values) via the invokeFunction call.

---

Solution:

```
// The following parameter names are JAVASCRIPT variable names.
String script = "function sendMail(username, email, body) { ..";

// And pass correct arguments (values), in order. The variables used
// here are JAVA variables, and align by-position with the JS parameters.
inv.invokeFunction("sendMail", username, email, "EMAIL SENT!!!!");
```

In addition, the `getElementById` (invalid ID) is wrong, the `body` parameter is never used, and `encodeURIComponent` should be used (instead of `escape`).

Comment: @Nicolas After fixing the script parmeters, yes. Make sure that the parameters match up as well - where is "EMAIL SENT!!!" going?

Comment: String script = "`function sendMail(" + username + "," + email + ")" ..` is *still* wrong, per above -- **print/log the contents of the `script` variable before you eval it (or attach a debugger).** You *must* look at the relevant data to debug your problems!

Comment: I printed script and it's working: function sendMail(blabla,blabla@gmail.com)

Comment: That is **not** correct code and is indeed *invalid* JavaScript (try running the contents of `script` in a browser console). Re-read the Hint/Solution sections. Trivially, try running this in a browser: `function f(a@b) {}` - What error do you get? (It might not be the exact error message, but it's invalid for the same reason in either case: *parameters* are variables, are not values!)

Comment: You mean they should be *parameters names*? Or they should be Strings?

Comment: Parameters are *variables*, not strings/values. `function f("text") { /* this is wrong */ }`; vs `function f(text) { alert(text) }; f("text")`. In the latter case, `f` was *invoked* supplying the *value* ("text") as an *argument* which was bound to the *parameter* (declared as) `text` inside the function. The first syntax is of course, invalid just as `function f(blah@blah.com) { /* wrong still, blah@blah.com is an invalid identifier/syntax */ }` is invalid. Parameters are *variables* (which evaluate to values) but are *not* values.

Comment: I recorrected it but still not working... When I print *script* am I supposed to see the value of username and email in the email message? Cause I don't...

Comment: No. You will/should **not** see any values when printing `script`. You should see parameter names. And, **Parameters are *variables* (which evaluate to values) but are not *values***. The *values* are supplied to the function via *arguments* - as specified with `invokeFunction`.

Comment: Because it is invalid JavaScript. Can you *run* the function declaration, which is the contents of `script`, in a browser without errors?

Comment: Ha, thank you! I find the little "s that were bugging me. If by any luck you've used this type of implementation before, do you know how long does it take before it actually send an email?

Comment: @Nicolas Nope, I have no idea. I'm not even sure if it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a typo or not:

```
    result = request.executeQuery("SELECT user.login, user.email "
                    + "FROM user " + );
```

It looks like you are missing the end of your statement.

Comment: While this is a problem, and the posted Java won't compile, it's not related to the reported error. Presumably it's an error generated during posting.

Comment: Yes it's a typo. Anyway, this part is compiling correctly, I get the right info in login and user.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm, your function definition:

```
function sendMail("username","email") {...}
```

doesn't look like valid JavaScript to me, apart of that, you never call the function.

Pseudocode, how to do it:

```
function sendMail(username, email) {
    var link = "jadajada" + email; // .... etc
}
sendMail("+username+","+email+");
```

Comment: My function is already sendMail(username,email) and not: function sendMail("username","email") ... *no?*